# CSS background-colour will not change on mobile device

Tags: html, css

Bascially, my CSS `background-color:` will not change the background color on the mobile screen I am using (**Samsung S9**). The peculiar thing for me is that the color is successfully changing on both desktop and a larger mobile device (**Ipad**) I am using for testing.

I have completely erased the color that is displaying on the smaller mobile screen (*#C96567*) from the single CSS file I am using, however, issue persists.

I don't have any media queries in the CSS file, as I initally thought this may have been the issue and I have attempted to use 'media='only screen and `(max-device-width: 480px`)' to try and force the CSS to apply the rule to the small screen.

As I am a new user, Stack won't allow me to embed my images to the post, so please find below links for 2 screenshots of desktop and mobile so you can see what I am talking about. They are the same page 'login.php'.

Any thoughts or advice on what the issue is? Like I said, I have never ran into this problem before and I am stuck as to what to do!

```
/* CSS sheet in question */
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"/>




/*CSS code*/

body, html {
    background-color: #3AAFA9;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.main { 
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    color: #3AAFA9;
}

.btn {
    background-color: #314455;
    border: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;    
    left: 10%;
}

.btn:hover
{  
    background-color:#B19F9E;
}

.quote {
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 80px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #FCF5F5;
    background-color: #3AAFA9;
}

.header-wrapper {

    background-color: #D3CED4;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10000;
}

.header-wrapper a.logo {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

[Desktop 'login.php' page for example (Color successfully changes)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5F46.png)

[Mobile 'login.php' page for example (Color not changed at all)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kVaF.jpg)

```
/*HTML Code*/ 

    <html>
            <head>
                <title>BackChannel</title>
                <meta charset="windows-1252">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=yes">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
                integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>               
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"/>

            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="container main">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md">
                            <form method="POST">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="emailAddress">Student Number</label>
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="studentNumber" id="studentNumber" placeholder="Student Number">

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group form-check">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="rememberMe">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="rememberMe">Remember me</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                                </fieldset>
                            </form> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card quote">              
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
                            <p>"The roots of education are bitter, but the fruit is sweet"</p>
                            <footer class="blockquote-footer">Aristotle <cite title="Source Title"></cite></footer>
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML as well please, so we can take a look

Comment: Do I see it correctly, that the issue is only on Safari? Because I have also encountered this problem when trying to set the body background color and needed to add workaround (repeated image background worked).

Comment: HTML code added. Also this seems to be a chrome issue, works fine wth firefox and safari.

Comment: Can you load it into developer tools and inspect the style inheritance hierarchy to see what's overriding it? That would be one quick way to find your culprit. On that note, do you get any result if you add `!important` to the end of your `background-color` declaration?